# Marketo Leads - How to find the updated values of progressionStatus field

Tags: marketo

I need to get the Marketo Leads who have changes on "progressionStatus" field (inside membership) with the API.
I can get all the leads related to a Program (with Get Leads by ProgramID API) without issues, but my need is to get those Leads with changes on "progressionStatus" column. 
I was thinking to use the CreatedAt / UpdatedAt fields of the Program, so then, get all the leads related to those programs. But I didn't get the accurate results that I want.
Also, I tried to use the GET Lead changes API and use "fields" parameter to "progressionstatus" but that field don't exist.

It is possible to resolve this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which API are you using? REST or SOAP? And also, what programming language?

Comment: Hi, I'm using Get Leads by Program REST API, with TaskFactory component in SSIS. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the list of Leads with progression status change by querying against the [Get Lead Activities](http://developers.marketo.com/rest-api/endpoint-reference/lead-database-endpoint-reference/#/Activities/getLeadActivitiesUsingGET) endpoint.

The [Get Lead Changes](http://developers.marketo.com/rest-api/endpoint-reference/lead-database-endpoint-reference/#!/Activities/getLeadChangesUsingGET) endpoint could sound as a good candidate, but that endpoint only returns changes on the lead fields. Progression status change is not stored on the lead directly, so at the end that won't work. On the other hand the [Get Leads by ProgramId](http://marketohost.wpengine.com/rest-api/endpoint-reference/lead-database-endpoint-reference/#!/Leads/getLeadsByProgramIdUsingGET) endpoint returns –amongst others– the actual value of `progressionStatus` (program status of the lead in the parent program) but not the “*change*” itself, so you cannot process the resultset based on that.

The good news is that the progression status change is an *activity type* and luckily we have the above mentioned Get Lead Activities endpoint (which is also mentioned as the [Query](http://developers.marketo.com/rest-api/lead-database/activities/#query) in the API docs) available to query just that. This endpoint also allows for filtering by `activityTypeIds` to narrow down the resultset to a single *activity type*.

Basically you have to call the `GET /rest/v1/activities.json` enpoint and pass the values of `activityTypeIds` and `nextPageToken` as query parameters (next to the access token obviously). So, first you need to get the internal Id of the *activity type* called “Change Status in Progression”. You can do that by querying the [GET /rest/v1/activities/types.json](http://developers.marketo.com/rest-api/endpoint-reference/lead-database-endpoint-reference/#!/Activities/getAllActivityTypesUsingGET) endpoint and look for a record with that *name*. (I don't know if this Id changes from instance to instance, but in ours it is the #104). Also, to obtain a `nextPageToken` you have to make a call to [GET /rest/v1/activities/pagingtoken.json](http://developers.marketo.com/rest-api/endpoint-reference/lead-database-endpoint-reference/#!/Activities/getActivitiesPagingTokenUsingGET) as well, where you have to specify the earliest datetime to retrieve activities from. See more about [Paging Tokens](http://developers.marketo.com/rest-api/paging-tokens/).

Once you have all of these bits at hand, you can make your request like that:

```
GET https://<INSTANCE_ID>.mktorest.com/rest/v1/activities.json?activityTypeIds=<TYPE_ID>&nextPageToken=<NEXTPAGE_TOKEN>&access_token=<ACCESS_TOKEN>
```

The result it gives is an array with items like below, which is easy to process further.

```
{
    "id":712630,
    "marketoGUID":"712630",
    "leadId":824864,
    "activityDate":"2017-12-01T08:51:13Z",
    "activityTypeId":104,
    "primaryAttributeValueId":1104,
    "primaryAttributeValue":"PROGRAM_NAME",
    "attributes":[
        {"name":"Acquired By","value":true},
        {"name":"New Status ID","value":33},
        {"name":"Old Status ID","value":32},
        {"name":"Reason","value":"Filled out form"},
        {"name":"Success","value":false},
        {"name":"New Status","value":"Filled-out Form"},
        {"name":"Old Status","value":"Not in Program"}
    ]
}
```

Knowing the `leadId`s in question, you can make yet another request to fetch the actual lead records.

Comment: Thanks so much @dferenc! So in that way, I will have a list of all the leads with changes in Progression Status column. Then, I will find the related programs to that leads, and then I will call Get Leads by Program API in order to get Progression Status column, I'm right? or there is a simpler way to get the Progression Status column?

Comment: As you can see in the sample response, you will have the internal ids for both the "old" and the "new" statuses (e.g. 32, and 33 in the answer). So in case you now what are the ids, you might not need to do additional queries. However, as there are no Lead details in this response, you might need to query for that. I have the above tested in php. In case you need it, I can add that to my answer.

Comment: Got it. Thanks a lot!